# Accessing a linked list from outside file

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a C program header.h file that has this linked list and declaration:

```
typedef struct _seg
{
    int bits[256];        // # of bits in array = 256

    struct _seg *next;    // link to the next segment
} seg;  

EXTERN seg *head;         // this points to the start of the linked list
```

In my `main.c`, I have:

```
seg * p;
head = NULL;
...
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {    // N is a parameter; irrelevant for this problem
    p = ( seg *) malloc(sizeof (seg));    // make a new segment
    p->next = head;        // add the new segment to the list
    head = p;
}
```

I call a function `clearAll()` from my `main.c` file, and in the `functions.c` function I have:

```
void clearAll() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        p->bits[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to clear all of the bits (set them equal to 0) in the bit array. Every time I compile there is an error that says that `'p' undeclared (first use in this function)` even though I have the `#include "header.h"` statement. I would just like to be able to reference and access the linked list and the arrays in it.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit for clarity based on new information in comments]

**Precise reason for the error:** The variable `p` is a local variable in another function.  In this case, `p` only exists (on the stack) during the execution of that function, so it is undefined inside `clearAll`.

**Recommendation:** As @ErikN suggests, pass in the list head to `clearAll`.  You have assigned storage for the list head in another module, making it a global variable.  Although this will work (may get a compiler warning about it being unresolved, but the linker will resolve it), it's unnecessary coupling to do it this way.

Also, it looks like `clearAll` only works on the head node, not the rest of the list.  So you'll probably want to walk the other nodes in the list as well.

Comment: Yeah I edited the question to include the `head` pointer. It was declared in my header.h file

Comment: Then simply use `head` instead of `p` in `clearAll`. :)  However, you'll have another problem in that only the first node will be cleared.  You'll probably want to walk the linked list and clear the other nodes too.

Comment: Okay so I did `head->bits[i] = 0;` but I get an `undefined reference to 'head'` message. Not sure if this is okay because it doesn't explicitly say error...but thanks! EDIT: I think it has this message because I'm only compiling the `functions.c` file, and head is initialized in `main.c`. So I think your suggestion helped in the end :)

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing your whole source code, but it's probably just a warning from the compiler, since the compiler doesn't see the actual storage assigned to `head` and ends up putting an open reference to it in the object code.  When your linker joins `main.o` with `functions.o`, it should be able to resolve the reference.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, I think you should pass a node to the `clearAll` function as an argument. Change the function signature to accept it as a paremeter:

`void clearAll(seg* listHead);`

Import the header that contains this `clearAll` declaration into your main.c file.
This way, you have a more generic function that can operate on any list, not just that particular one.